# Consecutive maps execution order in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

For the following example :

```
 this.service.retrieveObject(id).map((object)=>{ return function1(object); })
                                .map((object)=>{ return function2(object); });
```

I noticed in this example that `function2` is called before `function1`. How can I change the order of mapping executions without changing the order of calls ?

**NB:** in my code the calls are made in two different files that oblige me to not change the order

Comment: I dont see any nested maps, only consecutive

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo vocabulary corrected, TY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which rxjs operator to make extra transformation after mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283462/which-rxjs-operator-to-make-extra-transformation-after-mapping)

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't have a reason to create an unnamed function inside of the map, you should be able to just call .map(function1).map(function2)