# Which rxjs operator to make extra transformation after mapping?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
 this.service.retrieveObject(id).map((object)=>{ return transformation1(object); })
                                .map((object)=>{ return transformation2(object); });
```

In the exemple bellow the second `map` call doesn't have access to object after `transformation1` exexuted.

Which operator do I need to use to make nested transformations (transformation2 over transformation1)?

Comment: The second `map()` receives the result from calling the first `map()`. Or you want the second `map()` to work with the original `object`? Then what is the first `map()` for?

Comment: do transformation1 and/ or transformation2 return observables?

Answer (score 1):

`map` is the correct operator to make transformations.  `map` is essentially an `a -> b` function where you input an `a` and output a `b`.  Any subsequent calls to `map` would get the output object.

The downside the calling `map` twice is that you are effectively iterating over the object twice.  While on small objects that might not be a big deal, but take a large list and performance will decrease.  You can effectively combine your `transformation1` and `transformation2` functions into a single function and only call `map` once.  Or make `transformation2` take the return object from `transformation1`.  It would be more efficient to combine both operations into a single call.

```
this.service.retrieveObject(id)
    .map(object => transformation2(transformation1(object)));
```

**UPDATE 1/17/2018**

If transformation1 and transformation2 are asynchronous, what about using `switchMap`?  `switchMap` takes the result from the first observable and passes it to the second observable.

```
this.service.retrieveObject(id)
    .switchMap(retrieveObjectResponse => transformation1(retrieveObjectResponse))
    .switchMap(transformation1Response => transformation2(transformation1Response));
```

Comment: This is not possible in my case since transformation1 and transformation2 are two functions that belong to two different services

Comment: @user2080105 if they're asynchronous that would explain why they're firing in different order. The default map behaviour is nested behaviour.

Comment: Exactly, transformation1 and transformation2 are asynchrounous, I can't find a way to tell transformation 2 to wait for transformation1

Comment: If transformation1 and transformation2 are asynchronous, what about using switchMap?

Comment: **transformation1 and transformation2 are asynchrounous, I can't find a way to tell transformation 2 to wait for transformation1** - then please post the code for `transformation1`, it's return value should be an observable or a promise, in which case wrap it in `mergeMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: Oh, as per @TylerJennings update (except `mergeMap` might suffice).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one !

```
this.service.retrieveObject(id).map((object)=>{ return transformation1(object); })
                               .flatMap((object)=>{ return transformation2(object); });
```